# Does the Markov property always hold for a state-space structure?

Tags: self-study, markov-process, state-space-models, linear-dynamical-system

**Markov Property**: $p({\bf x}_t | {\bf x}_1, \ldots, {\bf x}_{t-1}) = p({\bf x}_t | {\bf x}_{t-1})$

Consider the following model for which the hidden states are ${\bf x}_t$ and the observations are ${\bf y}_t$:
\begin{align}
{\bf x}_t &= A_1 {\bf x}_{t-1} + A_2 {\bf x}_{t-2} + \cdots + A_p {\bf x}_{t-p} + {\bf w}_t, && {\bf w}_t \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} \mathcal{N}({\bf 0}, \Sigma_w) \tag{1} \\
{\bf y}_t &= B_0 {\bf x}_t + B_1 {\bf x}_{t-1} + \cdots + B_r {\bf x}_{t-r} + {\bf v}_t, && {\bf v}_t \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} \mathcal{N}({\bf 0}, \Sigma_v) \tag{2}
\end{align}

Assuming that $p<r$ and that all $A_i$ and $B_j$ are conformable, I can use block-matrix multiplication to give this model a state-space representation as follows:

\begin{align}
\vec{{\bf x}}_t &= A \vec{{\bf x}}_{t-1} + \vec{{\bf w}}_t, && \vec{{\bf w}}_t \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(0, e_1' e_1 \otimes \Sigma_w) \tag{3} \\
{\bf y}_t &= B \vec{{\bf x}}_t + {\bf v}_t, && {\bf v}_t \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma_v) \tag{4}
\end{align}
where $\vec{{\bf x}}_t = \begin{bmatrix}
{\bf x}_t \\ {\bf x}_{t-1} \\ \vdots \\ {\bf x}_{t-r}
\end{bmatrix}$, 
$A =
\begin{bmatrix}
A_1 & A_2 & \cdots & A_p & 0 &\cdots & 0 \\
I & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 &\cdots & 0 \\
0 & I & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & I & 0 & \cdots & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$, 
$\vec{{\bf w}}_t = 
\begin{bmatrix}
{\bf w}_t \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}$,

$B= 
\begin{bmatrix}
B_0 & B_1 & \cdots & B_r
\end{bmatrix},$ $e_1$ is a unit vector of conformable length, i.e. $e_1 = (1, 0, \ldots, 0)$, and $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product.

Typically, when you're working with a state-space model (SSM) you make the assumption that the Markov property holds. So some refer to it as the "Markov assumption."

> The model above is not a state-space model, but as I have shown it can be given the state-space structure. So is the state-space structure sufficient for the Markov property to be true? In other words, is it true that  $$p(\vec{{\bf x}}_t | \vec{{\bf x}}_1, \ldots, \vec{{\bf x}}_{t-1}) = p(\vec{{\bf x}}_t | \vec{{\bf x}}_{t-1})$$
>   because of the state-space structure?

In some papers it seems that merely having this structure is enough to say that the Markov property holds, e.g. [Dynamic Hierarchical Factor Models](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.415.6980&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (see page 7 and appendix A-1).

---

**EDIT:** 
Same question seems to be asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3253996/is-it-correct-to-say-a-state-space-model-has-the-markov-property

Looking back at this question, the answer seems to be trivial. My mathematical training makes a clear difference between what is *assumed to be true* and what *needs to be proven*.

For SSMs (and for non-SSMs that can put into a state-space form), it seems that assuming the Markov property to be true (i.e. making the Markov assumption) is redundant because, as user @hejseb says, "it is precisely the conditional independence structure that you have." It's not an assumption you need to make because it's already true.

Comment: Yes, as you show that is precisely the conditional independence structure that you have.

Comment: I see. So it is not necessary to actually show that the LHS of $p(\vec{{\bf x}}_t | \vec{{\bf x}}_1, \ldots, \vec{{\bf x}}_{t-1}) = p(\vec{{\bf x}}_t | \vec{{\bf x}}_{t-1})$ actually equals the right?

Comment: I don't know why you need to show that. I think most people view it as a trivial matrix product.

Comment: In a lot of cases I've come across, there's no need to actually show the LHS equals the RHS because they make it an assumption for the state-space model. I'm not working with a state-space model -- I just show this model can have the same structure. If the state-space structure implies that the Markov property holds, then there's no need to make the assumption.

Comment: The fact that many modelers couple the state-space model with the Markov assumption tells me that the state-space structure itself doesn't imply that the Markov Property holds.

Comment: @hejseb: If you put your first comment as an answer, then I will accept it.

Comment: @grxxvtony: I think you're making too much of what the markov property means. All it means is that, if you have the latest- current estimate of the state, then that is all you need for the next prediction of the response. You don't need the values of the previous state estimates because all that information is in the current estimate of the state. Note that this is  property of the state space formulation. So, as far as I know, state space implies markov property. I'm glad to be corrected if this is not the case.

Comment: @mlofton: Understood. I believe the culprit, if you will, to be authors who state as assumption that the Markov property holds for a state-space model. The fact that they are assuming it to be true led me to believe that it's not true in general for state-space models, because if it did then there would be no need to make the assumption. If it is true that today is Saturday, then there's no need for me to assume that today is Saturday, you know?

Comment: @grxxvtony: yeah, I agree.  To me, the state space formulation IMPLIES the markov property. It scares me a little though if books/references say that because I would think that, if you're doing state space modelling, you know a reasonable amount about it ??? Could we be incorrect ? I don't think so but there's always that possibility !!!!!! Always good to have an opened mind. Definitely looking forward to hearing if anyone disagrees-has a different viewpoint etc.

Comment: @grxxvtony: I think we are still correct but to be slightly picky, the property does depend on formulatiing the states correctly. The bottom of page 3 explains it better than I could. So, I would think of it as: If one chooses the states so that the state space model can be formulated, then it is markov.  http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~stine/stat910/lectures/14_state_space.pdf